# Can hackers behind the ransomware WannaCry be traced through bitcoin transactions?

Tags: privacy, hacking, traceability, ransomware

Can hackers behind the ransomware WannaCry be traced through bitcoin transactions? Is there is central server of Bitcoin where all transactions can be looked up from? And is it possible to identify hackers from IP address used to access their Bitcoin accounts?

Answer (score 1):

> Can hackers behind the ransomware WannaCry be traced through bitcoin
>   transactions?

no, if they are smart enough

> Is there is central server of bitcoin

no

> where all transactions can be looked up from?

yes

> And is it possible to identify hackers from IP address used to access
>   their bitcoin accounts?

no